# Provision a sharepoint hosted workflow to the host web via JSOM?

Tags: workflow, jsom, sharepoint-on-prem, provisioning

I know it's possible to create lists and groups in the host web. What I'd like to accomplish is to create a list on the host web and then be able to add a workflow to that list. Is this possible with JSOM?

For example a simple workflow that sends an email to a group of users when an item is created.

I looked at integrated workflows, but they only seem to be available with sharepoint online.